# Vuejs, call API from the base URL its hosted on

Tags: api, vue.js, hosting

**Short question:**(assuming my vue app and its backend are hosted on the same place) Can i fetch APIs from a URL vue is hosted on instead of inserting a fixed url in the api string, so by changing the domain, i wont have to change the code.

**Long description:** Lets say im running my vue app on localhost, talking to backend(.net in my case) via APIs which is hosted on `example.com`, so my api looks something like `fetch("https://www.example.com/api/myFunction")`.
Now im building my vue app and adding the built (dist) folder to the backend, so any request to `example.com` would be sent to backend, which then opens my index.html folder, and i want my api to (instead of how it is above) be like `fetch("[SOMETHING]/api/myFunction")` where [SOMETHING] is either a built in character that refers to root or a variable containing my base URL using js functions or vue libraries like Vue-router so that i wont have to change the URL in my code if i ever move the entire server from `example.com` to lets say `myapp.com`.

I am using vue CLI v 3.0.0